# Delphi DBLookupCombox Autocomplete

Tags: delphi

I have a DBLookupcombobox connected to a dbgrid. Is it possible to set auotcomplete, that is when you start typing in the field it takes the value. Right now when I type in the field , it disappear when you move to another field in the dbgrid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have refresh the dataset or datasoure when you miss the focus?Check it.